# How to Host an Uncensored AI Model in Budget

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model, llama, huggingface-hub

I am building an app and need to use uncensored model such as -

https://huggingface.co/georgesung/llama2_7b_chat_uncensored

https://huggingface.co/mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1

Its expensive to host it on hugging face inference API. Please suggest if there is any other alternative which is cheaper or any platform which provides usage based APIs for the same?

Thanks in advance.